# Java set security permission of created instances

Tags: java, permissions, securitymanager

So I have a bit of code, that creates an instance of a class.

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName("MyClass");
Constructor<?> cons = c.getConstructor();
cons.setAccessible(true);
Object instance = cons.newInstance();
```

Now I want to set some restrictions to that instance. When I call:

```
instance.doSomething();
```

I want to set restrictions for that bit of code (of the instance). So the methods called from that isntance can not do something fishy (System calls, File operations...).

I have tried to set a security manager, but that restricts all of the code (I still want to read/write files for the rest of my code).
Is it possible to restrict only certain objects?

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR: [Code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b8dcdd33fb838829b16e41d82b59fcab)**

---

The question is essentially *"How do I invoke a method on a particular instance, with privileges lower than normal?"*. There are three requirements here:

1. Code is to be authorized on a per-instance basis. An instance is privileged by default.
2. An instance may be selectively blacklisted, i.e., it may be accorded lower privileges than it normally would have been, *for the duration* of a method invocation that it receives.
3. Blacklisting must propagate to code executed on the receiver's behalf, specifically any objects of the same type that it interacts with, itself included; otherwise, if, say, the receiver were in turn to call

   ```
   AccessController.doPrivileged((PrivilegedAction<Void>) () -> {
       this.doSomethingElse();
       return null;
   });
   ```

   `doSomethingElse()` would escape the sandbox.

All three are problematic:

- The first one is not really<sup>1</sup> achievable, because it presupposes that the runtime maintain—*and expose*—information about the instances (rather than merely the classes) on threads' execution stacks, which it does not<sup>2</sup>.
- The second and third are only achievable as long as any blacklisted code *does not* assert its own (default, class-based) privileges via `AccessController.doPrivileged(...)`, which, by design, it may at any time choose to.

*Is there an alternative?*
Well, how far are you willing to go? Modify `AccessController` / `AccessControlContext` internals? Or worse yet, internals of the VM? Or perhaps provide your own `SecurityManager` that reimplements the aforementioned components' functionality from scratch, in a way that satisfies your requirements? If the answer to all is "no", then I fear that your options are limited.

As an aside, you should ideally be able to make a binary choice when asked *"Can or cannot this particular code, i.e. **class**, be entrusted with the particular privileges?"*, for this would tremendously simplify<sup>3</sup> things. Unfortunately you cannot; and, to make matters worse, neither can you, presumably, modify the implementation of the class such that all of its instances can either be considered—with regards to a specific set of privileges—trustworthy or not, nor do you wish to simply mark the class, and therefore all of its instances, as untrusted (which I do believe you should!) and live with it.

Moving on to the proposed workaround. To overcome the shortcomings listed earlier, the original question will be rephrased as follows: *"How do I invoke a method with **elevated** privileges accorded to **the method receiver's `ProtectionDomain`**?"* I am going to answer this derivative question instead, suggesting, in contrast to the original one, that:

1. Code is to be authorized by the `ProtectionDomain` of its class, as is normally the case. Code is sandboxed by default.
2. Code may be selectively whitelisted, for the duration of a method invocation under a particular thread.
3. Whitelisting must propagate<sup>4</sup> to code of the same class called by the receiver.

The revised requirements will be satisfied by means of a custom `ClassLoader` and `DomainCombiner`. The purpose of the first is to assign a distinct `ProtectionDomain` per class<sup>5</sup>; the other's is to temporarily replace the domains of individual classes within the current `AccessControlContext` for "on-demand whitelisting" purposes. The `SecurityManager` is additionally extended to prevent thread creation by unprivileged code<sup>4</sup>.

---

Note: I relocated the code to [**this gist**](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b8dcdd33fb838829b16e41d82b59fcab) to keep the post's length below the limit.
Standard disclaimer: **Proof-of-concept code—take with several tablespoons of salt!**

---

**Running the example**
Compile and deploy the code as suggested by the example policy configuration file, i.e., there should be two<sup>6</sup> *unrelated* classpath *entries* (e.g. sibling directories at the filesystem level)—one for classes of the `com.example.trusted` package, and another for `com.example.untrusted.Nasty`.

Ensure also that you have replaced the policy configuration with the example one, and have modified the paths therein as appropriate.

Lastly run (after having appropriately modified the classpath entries, of course):

```
java -cp /path/to/classpath-entry-for-trusted-code:/path/to/classpath-entry-for-untrusted-code -Djava.system.class.loader=com.example.trusted.DiscriminatingClasspathClassLoader com.example.trusted.Main
```

The first call to the untrusted method should hopefully succeed, and the second fail.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>It would perhaps be possible for instances of a specially crafted class (having, e.g., a domain of their own, assigned by some trusted component) to exercise their own privileges *themselves* (which does not hold true in this case, since you have no control over the implementation of `instance`'s class, it appears). Nevertheless, this would still not satisfy the second and third requirement.</sub>
<sup>2</sup> <sub>Recall that, under the default `SecurityManager`, a `Permission` is granted when all `ProtectionDomain`s—to which normally classes, rather than instances, are mapped—of the thread's `AccessControlContext` [imply](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/ProtectionDomain.html#implies-java.security.Permission-) that permission.</sub>
<sup>3</sup> <sub>You would then simply have to grant permissions at the policy level, if you deemed the class trustworthy, or otherwise grant nothing at all, rather than have to worry about permissions per instance per security context and whatnot.</sub>
<sup>4</sup> <sub>This is a hard decision: If whitelisting did not affect subsequent callees of the same type, the instance would not be able to call any privilege-requiring methods *on itself*. Now that it does, on the other hand, any other instance of the same type, that the original whitelisted method receiver interacts with, become privileged too! Thus you must ensure that the receiver *does not* call any "untrusted" instances of its own kind. It is for the same reason a bad idea to allow the receiver to spawn any threads.</sub>
<sup>5</sup> <sub>As opposed to the strategy employed by the default application `ClassLoader`, which is to group all classes that reside under the same classpath entry within a single `ProtectionDomain`.</sub>
<sup>6</sup> <sub>The reason for the inconvenience is that the `ProtectionDomain`, which our custom application `ClassLoader`'s class gets mapped to by its parent, has a `CodeSource` implying all  `CodeSource`s referring to files under the loader's classpath entry. So far so good. Now, when asked to load a class, our loader attempts to discern between system/extension classes (loading of which it delegates to its parent) and application classes, by testing whether the .class file is located below `JAVA_HOME`. Naturally, to be allowed to do so, it requires read access to the filesystem subtree beneath `JAVA_HOME`. Unfortunately, granting the corresponding privilege to our loader's (notoriously broad) domain, implicitly grants the privilege to the domains of all other classes residing beneath the loader's classpath entry, including untrusted ones, as well. And that should hopefully explain why classpath entry-level isolation between trusted and untrusted code is necessary. There are of course workarounds, as always; e.g. mandating that trusted code be additionally signed in order to accrue any privileges; or perhaps using a more flexible URL scheme for code source identification, and/or altering code source implication semantics.</sub>

---

Further reading:

- [Default Policy Implementation and Policy File Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html)
- [API for Privileged Blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/doprivileged.html)
- [Secure Coding Guidelines for Java SE - §9 - Access Control](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html#9)
- [Troubleshooting Security](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/troubleshooting-security.html)

---

Historical note: Originally this answer proposed a nearly identical solution that <s>abused</s>relied on JAAS's `SubjectDomainCombiner`, rather than a custom one, for dynamic privilege modification. A "special" `Principal` would be attached to specific domains, which would then accrue additional `Permission`s upon evaluation by the `Policy`, based on their composite `CodeSource`-`Principal` identity.