# How to create newInstance with enabled SecurityManager in Java

Tags: java, security, securitymanager

I need to create new instance of a class loaded from untrusted classfile.
Now I do the following:

```
classLoader.loadClass(UNSTRUSTED_CLASS).newInstance()
```

The problem is that if I enable security manager it doesn't permit to call newInstance, but if I have security manager disabled one can put malicious code into initialization block and it executes with no problem.

How one accomplishes creating new instance of untrusted class?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36091323/java-set-security-permission-of-created-instances

Comment: @Akash I've looked at that question. There's sufficient difference as I can isolate method calls, but can't isolate instantiation. unfortunately, Answer on that question doesn't help also.

Comment: Can't you isolate the trusted calling type from the potentially untrusted callee, such that the former's `ProtectionDomain` can be granted (via `Policy` or `ClassLoader`) the necessary instantiation privileges, while the latter's is still subject to (strict) access control?

Comment: that's what I was trying to achieve, didn't know how
now I know and shared as the answer

Comment: Why on earth would you have a `SecurityManager` and not want it to apply to untrusted code?

Comment: I want to apply to intrusted code, but NOT to apply to my code (calling reflection API)
So my trusted code instantiates object of untrusted class
I want security manager to be enabled while executing initialization+constructor of untrusted class, but to allow me to use reflection in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what I used.
As far as I have custom class loader which loads untrusted code from specific location I could define code base in policy file for my trusted code, which I granted permission to use reflection. Thus untrusted code from another codebase don't have this permission.
i.e.

```
grant codeBase "file:/C:/path/to/trusted/code/classes" {
     permission java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission "suppressAccessChecks";
};
```

With this policy file all code loaded from other locations than specified in codeBase will not have any permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The static initialiser and constructors of a class will always execute with that class on the stack, and hence the appropriate `ProtectionDomain` in the `AccessControlContext`. That's not to say there may be other issues with, for instance, actually getting a class from a parent class loader, giving access to the current `Thread`/`ThreadGroup`/`AppContext`/`ThreadLocal`s.

Other than that, the three-arg `Class.forName` allows loading a class without initialisation. However, it's probably more typical to load the class using code in a parent class loader.